# Manage Firebase user accounts

Tags: firebase, firebase-admin

I have an administrative panel that lists all users on my system. I would like to be able to delete the account of a saved user in `firebase.auth()`.

I know the firebase provides an SDK for this, but I do not have a server on Node, my site is hosted directly on Firebase hosting.

Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a Cloud Function (serverless) that deletes users using the Node.js Admin SDK. Then you can hit that endpoint whenever you want to delete a user: https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions

Answer (score 0):

You do have a node server. It's free. You can install node on your laptop or even better you can stand one up online. I use the free tier of [cloud9 IDE](https://c9.io/login) (I do not work for them and I'm not trying to sell anything).

Easiest of all, use Firebase's web console to delete a user, unless you have a need to build out a more elaborate system.